# Connecting QGIS to ArcGIS world imagery?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-online-basemaps

Have connected QGIS to ArcGIS World Imagery using python console as described on http://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-adding-an-arcgis-rest-service.  QGIS Seems to connect and make a raster layer the image is not correct.

I'm very new to QGIS.

[image: Problem with World Imagery]

Comment: I was able to connect just fine using `qgis.utils.iface.addRasterLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer?f=json&pretty=true","raster")`.  However, at a scale of approx 1:780 the image went crazy with colors, similar to what you are showing.

Comment: I have the same problem. Help me please

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: I use Qgis Desktop 1.8.0 and I don't have this problem. But the zoom is limited.

Answer (score 5):

This question appears to have resurfaced so it is worth adding an updated answer.

Adding ArcGIS imagery and mapping is now easy in QGIS 3.x and you can add these services through the add data dialogue.

Navigate to the ESRI REST services directory: http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services

Copy the link location for whatever link you're interested in. For example world imagery: http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer -> the link needs to end with /MapServer

Open QGIS and launch the Data source Manager. On the left hand bar select ArcGIS Map Server.

Click new and paste the link into the URL box and give it a name. No need to add anything into the authentication section. Click OK and it will add the layer to the drop down.

[image: MapServer layer dialogue]

When you want to add it to the map select the relevant layer in the drop down and click Connect. You'll see the layer description pop up and then click add to add it into the TOC.